# SQLAlchemy ORM how to join query with table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have an ORM model in SQLAlchemy that stores some prices (by product_id and date) and exchange rates (by currency_from, currency_to and date). I have a function that returns a query object. The query has id, date, currency and price columns. Optionally the prices can be converted to another currency. I would like to take this query object as an argument and join it with `ExRates` table, to convert to different currency.

A workaround I use is to read the parts that I need to `pandas.DataFrame` and merge. Another tricky part is that sometimes I have a price for Saturday, but no ex rate. In that case last available ex rate should be used. Again in `pandas` I can do it with `.reindex` and `.fillna(method='ffill')`, but I would like to implement it purely in SQL.

For reference below are bits from my code:

```
class Price(ReprMixin, GenFromDfMixin, ToDfMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'prices'

    benchmark_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('benchmarks.benchmark_id'), index=True, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, index=True, primary_key=True)
    price = Column(Float)
    return_ytd = Column(Float)

class Benchmark(ReprMixin, GenFromDfMixin, ToDfMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'benchmarks'

    benchmark_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    index_name = Column(String)
    currency = Column(String)
    ...

class ExRate(ReprMixin, GenFromDfMixin, ToDfMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rates'

    cur_from = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    cur_to = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, primary_key=True, index=True)
    ex_rate = Column(Float)

def _query_by_id_and_date(benchmark_id, date_min=None, date_max=None):
    if date_min is None:
        date_min = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)
    if date_max is None:
        date_max = datetime.date(2222, 1, 1)
    prices = dal.session.query(Price.benchmark_id, Price.date, Price.price, Benchmark.currency).join(Benchmark)\
        .filter(Price.benchmark_id == benchmark_id).filter(Price.date.between(date_min, date_max))
    return prices

def _currency_convert(q, to_curr):
    pass  
# I would like to call this function like this:
# _currency_convert(_query_by_id_and_date('some_id'), 'EUR')
# and get the same 4 column query, but with prices converted to a new currency
```

Comment: Create a subquery of ExRate table using the filter on currency and join your prices table with subquery.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have understood your problem correctly. I think you are trying to convert the prices based on different currencies. Give it try

```
from sqlalchemy import and_    
query=session.query(Price.benchmark_id,Price.date,Price.return_ytd,Price.price*ExRate.ex_rate)\
        .join(Benchmark)\
        .join(ExRate, ExRate.cur_from==Benchmark.currency)\
        .filter(and_(ExRate.cur_from==Benchmark.currency, ExRate.cur_to=='EUR')
```

Comment: Just came back from holiday, I will give it a try today. I can already see one problem - the ex rates are also per date and your query does not seem to take it into consideration. I will also experiment with the subquery you suggested in comment.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using `and_` over chaining `.filter(...).filter(...)`?